# Error if XElement goes to Null

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following code:

```
var te = doc.Descendants("TESTID").Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber")= finalstr).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the case `te is null`, then the following gives an exeption:

```
var ignorete = doc.Descendants("IgnoreTESTID").Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber")== te.FirstAttribute.Value.toString();
```

The exception is : `Object not set to an instance of the Object`

How do I make `ignorete` to null if `te` goes null ?

Comment: what do you expect `null.FirstAttribute.Value.toString()` to do?

Comment: Dont do that :)

Comment: You appear to have posted an observation, not a question. Yes, you're correct, when `te is null` that line of code will generate an exception. And?

Comment: I want to put the `ignorete` to null as well if te goes null

Comment: That ^ is a statement of intent, again not a question...the clue is the lack of a `?`

Comment: How do I make `ignorete` to null if `te` goes null ?

Comment: `var ignorete = blabla = te?.blabla`

Comment: I just didn't know how to make it null if `te` goes null, so asking all to help me with this

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: `var ignorete = (te == null) ? null : doc.Descendants("IgnoreTESTID").Where(x=> etc`

Comment: @JohnWu for C#6 and above `var ignorete = te ?? doc.Descendants("IgnoreTESTID").Where(x=> etc`

Comment: @JohnWu & @@SeM: Thanks, that's what I was looking. I tried googling it but didn't knew what was the operator was called. May I know whats the technical term of this operator

Comment: Conditional operator or ternary operator. Added to my answer below.

Comment: use `te?.FirstAttribute`, that shall do the job. It will then not get an exception and will compare `(string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber")` to null, which shall provide an empty collection, then you can use `DefaultIfEmpty` for the null result for the `ignorete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a guard clause:

```
public string GetIgnorete()
{
    var te = doc.Descendants("TESTID").Where(x=>  (string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber") == finalstr).FirstOrDefault();
    if ( te == null ) return null;
    return doc.Descendants("IgnoreTESTID").Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber") == te.FirstAttribute.Value.toString();
}
```

Or you could just use the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
var ignorete = (te == null) ? null : doc.Descendants("IgnoreTESTID").Where( x => etc –
```

Note: I took the liberty of changing your `=` to a `==`. The latter is the equality operator which results in a Boolean based on the comparison. The former is the assignment operator whose result is the value of the assignment.

Comment: `(string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber")= te.FirstAttribute.Value.toString();`?

Comment: The code in this answer will not work. It's using an asignment operator `=` instead of a comparison operator `==` and it's missing a brace `.Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber")= te.FirstAttribute.Value.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because a `var` must be instatiated so that C# can assign a type. You cannot create a `var` object and set it to null.

In this case, you would need to declare it as whatever object type doc.Descendants returns. I've declared as a generic `object` below:

```
object ignorete = te != null ? doc.Descendants("IgnoreTESTID").Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber")= te.FirstAttribute.Value.toString()) : null;
```

Comment: `(string)x.Attribute("TESTIDNumber")= te.FirstAttribute.Value.toString();`?